# Repeat Row that is not header in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am trying to repeat one blank row of tablix on each page. But getting error.

I tried advance setting and repeat on each page = true.

It is showing some error that the row is dynamic. It is because it is after dynamic rows.

I even tried fixing rows. But that also didn't worked.